# Very simple flex animation not moving along x axis

Tags: animation, flex4, mxml

I'm trying to use Animate in MXML to move a button along X or Y axis.
My button increase width when clicked, but does not move at all. What is wrong with this code ? It should be something really simple, but I can't find it.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    initialize='init()'>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function init():void {}
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout id='l' horizontalAlign="left" />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Animate id="mover" target="{button}" duration="1000">
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" valueFrom="0" valueTo="100"/>
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" valueTo="100"/>
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="width" valueBy="20"/>
        </s:Animate>
    </fx:Declarations>  

    <s:Button id="button" click="mover.play()" label="Button"/>

</s:Application>
```

I got this sample from Adobe docs. I think it should be related to layout or something like that, but all my tries of changing layout, including into a Canvas or other tricks does not change anything : the button still stay at the same place.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: try increasing the length of the path. most cases 100 pixels may not be long enough .. try 600 right away , if still doensnt move than we will see..

Comment: Or have u already tried that?

Comment: Just tried with 600, the button still don't move... I also tried with a small valueBy for the width property (like 5), the button still increase in width.

Comment: try removing the function declaration and run only the script. I mean remove declaration tags

Comment: If I remove the declaration tag and let Animate at the same level than the button, the mxml does not compile. Without the Script tag the result is the same.

Comment: Does this example work when you tries it or does it give you the same result ? I suspect something wrong with my installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the use of the `VerticalLayout`. This layout, as well as the `HorizontalLayout`, ignores x/y properties of the objects that are being laid out.

If you remove your layout declaration altogether, it will then use the default `BasicLayout` which will honor the x/y properties and allow your animation to work.

Comment: You are right, the button move when removing the layout. Thanks for pointing it out !